# Play same game on two different platforms

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one, ios

My son has Minecraft on two different platforms (Xbox One and iOS 10).

He wants to continuously and seamlessly be able to move from one to the other: the Xbox at home, but iOS when mobile.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may share worlds across platforms using the [Minecraft Bedrock Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition)